# Not receiving pushes in xtify GCM sample app

Tags: xtify

I have built the xtify sample app and installed it on a device.  Through the xtify console, I can see that my device is registered.  When I use the "Test Implementation" feature of the xtify console, I receive the message.

However, broadcasts (both simple and rich) sent via the PushPoint Manager and the TARGET Manager are not being received.

**UPDATE**
When I hit the "Update Location" button in the sample app, I receive the rich pushes... shouldn't I be able to get the pushes even when the app isn't running?

Comment: Can't replicate this behavior using my GCM credentials and the sample app.  Have you tried sending a Push Point again since you posted this question?  Can you try pushing via our Push 2.x API?

Comment: I was never able to get rich pushes working reliably from the pushpoint manager.  However, they work perfectly using the 2.x api.  Weird.